# Split address field into two line in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I want to split a address input parameter field into to two lines; in a single line only 160 character (max) should be there, and it will be split from any space nearest to the 160th character. Please help!

e.g., if I have an address variable `pi_billing_adress`

```
pi_billing_adress :=  'MS-9/804, ABC Street , Sector - 56, near NFC market , Malviya Nagar , New Delhi India';
```

I have to take this address in two line divide from 160 character using below code.

```
SELECT position(' ' in reverse(SUBSTRING(pi_billing_adress,1, 160))) INTO v_space_postion;

v_billing_address_line1 := SUBSTRING(pi_billing_adress,1, (160-v_space_postion));

v_billing_address_line2 := SUBSTRING(pi_shipping_address, (v_address_lenghth-v_space_postion)+1,LENGTH(pi_shipping_address));

pi_billing_address := concat(v_billing_address_line1, chr(10), v_billing_address_line2 );
```

Comment: please post a reproducible example of your problem.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 1):

This will introduce a new-line instead of the first space before the 162nd position in the string:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(pi_billing_adress, E'^(.{1,160}) (.*)$', E'\\1\n\\2');
```

I'm not sure if that is what you need, but anyway it is a starting point for you.